# WAMP ~ custom url handling not working in project folder

Tags: php, wamp

**context:**

I've been trying to get a custom project (or small framework) working on WAMP for which i've created custom url handling, basically like laravel does.

e.g

http://localhost/project-folder/destination-to-execute ~ doesn't work

http://localhost/project-folder/ ~ works

Where everything after project-folder is responsible for routing to a function.

**problem:**

calling the root of the folder works fine, it is currrently set to return a json value to test, but i can't put anything after it (as explained above) or WAMP will say it can't find the specified url.

**What I've tried:**

- creating a virtual host and testing it ~ gives the same result
- restarting wamp
- switching php versions
- checking http mod rewrite (it's on)

I've worked on the project fine before but i reinstalled wamp and i've never been able to start it since and i couldn't find a good solution on the forums.

Answer (score 0):

I found out shortly after i posted this..

I've been using a third party service called STACK to sync folders between my desktop and my laptop. STACK has added certain files to their ignored files list because of the way they work, that includes .htaccess files.

I think the rest speaks for itself, my .htaccess file was missing and STACK didn't notify me of this, so when i checked my files i noticed it was missing and voila, i renamed it, synced it, renamed it again and it works.